# Flexbox and colspan

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox

Is there a way to get `flex`box and `colspan` working together? (I understand I can simply remove flex altogether. This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do)

The following seems to ignore the `colspan` attribute altogether

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="flex" colspan="2">Center</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something else</td>
    <td>Another thing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using `flex`? If you change an element to `display: flex` it's no longer `display: table-cell` so it's not treated as a `table-cell` element.

Comment: The easiest workaround is probably just to nest a `flex` element inside of the `td`. But depending on what it is you're actually putting together, there may be other solutions.